# Python - Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

Tags: python, pip

I'm having problems with pip not being able to install modules on windows.
I get the following error when entering the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Python310\Scripts>pip3 install requests
```

The output is as follows:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 173, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 203, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 315, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 94, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 472, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 140, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 128, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 29, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 272, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 851, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 798, in find_all_candidates
    page_candidates = list(page_candidates_it)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\sources.py", line 134, in page_candidates
    yield from self._candidates_from_page(self._link)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 758, in process_project_url
    html_page = self._link_collector.fetch_page(project_url)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 490, in fetch_page
    return _get_html_page(location, session=self.session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 400, in _get_html_page
    resp = _get_html_response(url, session=session)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\collector.py", line 115, in _get_html_response
    resp = session.get(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 555, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\session.py", line 454, in request
    return super().request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\adapter.py", line 53, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 359, in connect
    conn = self._connect_tls_proxy(hostname, conn)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\connection.py", line 500, in _connect_tls_proxy
    return ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 453, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 495, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1027, in _create
    raise ValueError("check_hostname requires server_hostname")
ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is a proxy issue or a permissions issue as this is on a works PC.

The message "*Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable*" is confusing me. So I've re-installed Python again. No joy.

I've tried adding in the proxy option on the pip command, and this returns the same error.

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: "*Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable*" is permission issue. "*ValueError: check_hostname requires server_hostname*" is firewall/proxy issue.

Comment: Thanks, I think the permissions issue may be due to our IT wanting to lock everything down and make my life the living hell that it is. I've noticed that the install folder doesn't have write or modify permissions set. So will get them to change this.